# Sum of Fibonacci sequence throws overflow error for large numbers

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, integer-overflow, largenumber

For smaller numbers, till r = 1472 the below code is working well and good.

**Code:**

```
import math
def fib(n):
    s5 = math.sqrt(5)
    phi = (1 + s5) / 2;
    return int(round(pow(phi, n) / s5));

def calculateSum(l, r):

    # Using our deduced result
    sum = fib(r + 2) - fib(l + 1)
    res = sum % 1000000007
    return res

l = 5
r =1400
print(calculateSum(l,r))
```

But when the r goes beyond 1473 it throws the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/spoj/FIBOSUM.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(calculateSum(l,r))
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/spoj/FIBOSUM.py", line 14, in calculateSum
    sum = fib(r + 2) - fib(l + 1)
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/spoj/FIBOSUM.py", line 9, in fib
    return int(round(pow(phi, n) / s5));
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And I referred and searched about this error and found a way to mitigate using this link [Error 34, Result too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497258/error-34-result-too-large). These changes are reflected below

**Code2:**

```
import decimal
def fib(n):
    s5 = decimal.Decimal(5).sqrt()
    phi = (1 + s5) / 2;
    return int(round(pow(phi, n) / s5));

def calculateSum(l, r):

    # Using our deduced result
    sum = fib(r + 2) - fib(l + 1)
    res = sum % 1000000007
    return res

l = 5
r =4500000
print(calculateSum(l,r))
```

These changes are works for the numbers approximately less than say r = 4550000 but a number larger than 5000000 throws the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/spoj/FIBOSUM.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(calculateSum(l,r))
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/spoj/FIBOSUM.py", line 14, in calculateSum
    sum = fib(r + 2) - fib(l + 1)
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/spoj/FIBOSUM.py", line 9, in fib
    return int(round(pow(phi, n) / s5));
decimal.Overflow: [<class 'decimal.Overflow'>]
```

Could anybody help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why do you need to compute the modulo of a sum of fibs above 5 million?

Comment: I am trying to solve this programming problem https://www.spoj.com/problems/FIBOSUM/